# Javascript Math.floor generating a lower number than expected

Tags: javascript, math, floor

I'm giving it a price as 19.90 and it ouputs 19.98, the original calculation is:

```
 $('#price').text((Math.floor(price * 100) / 100) + ' Euro');
```

Here's a JsFiddle just with the Math.floor part which is the one giving problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/dLNnp/

I'm expecting it to give 19.9 again!

Comment: so what are you trying to do?

Comment: Your parenthesis are placed wrong. `Math.floor(19.90)* 100;`

Comment: @Prisoner Just rounding up prices but they are generated based on what the user chooses, in this case it's not working.

Comment: @jurgemaister that will make it go 1900 which is not what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, you should maybe switch to [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to cope with the inaccuracies when using floating point arithmetic.

```
$('#price').text((Math.round(price * 100) / 100) + ' Euro');
```

When you look at the internal presentation, you will see something like this:

```
19.90 * 100
> 1989.9999999999998
```

JavaScript floating point numbers are not able to represent your number exactly, but use something close to your real number. When you now use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) on this value, you get `19.89` instead of `19.90`.

To get a general idea about the subject, I refer you to this question:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1169798)

Comment: This still returns 19.89 Euro for `price = 19.90`. OP's problem is parentheses.

Comment: @jurgemaister Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dLNnp/2/ | Edit: missed the change in the code example, sorry.